# Android update process - resources overridden?

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, resources, upgrade

currently I'm developing my first app for the Playstore. Now I am asking myself **how exactly the old resources are replaced or updated** when I put a new version of my app into the Playstore.
I have a csv-file in the raw-resources which is once (every time when the version-code in the Manifest-file changed) written in the sqlite-database. Now if I want to put new data to the database I would like to simply add new lines to the csv-file in the raw-folder, load the new apk-file to the Playstore where the new lines would then be written to the database.

And that is exactly the point where I am not sure whats happening: **if my csv-file has the same name as in the previous version - will the old version be overridden then?** I would think so for the raw resources are packaged into the apk-file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resources will be overriden. An apk update is just a unisntall from the old app and installing the new one, but keeping the app data (sharedpreferences + database). If you save your csv data in the app database with sqlite, then you can update the database with your new csv, but your raw file will be for sure overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

This is like any other file in your APK. The APK is essentially a ZIP archive.

Google Play uses the version code in the Manifest to determine recency - i.e. "in what order have you provided the APK files?"

However, your data loader will need to handle two scenarios - new install and update. That is not "automagically" handled by Google. In other words, just because you add data to a CSV file, that does not mean that existing installs will get that data. If you are doing real-time data requests from the raw file, then data will come from the new CSV file.